# Laravel 5 eager load a model without direct relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have..

**Models**:

```
Player
id,player_name

Sport
id,sports_name

Game
id,player_id,sports_id,scores
```

**Model Relationship**

**Player** *hasMany* **Games**, **Sports** *hasMany* **Games**, **Games** *belongsTo* **Player** and **Sports**.

---

Question: In **Controller**, is it **Possible** to load *Sports* and each *Games* per sports in every *Player*?

in a single query, i want to achieve in my **Blade** something like this..

```
@foreach($player as $p)
  @foreach ($p->sport as $ps) /*this wont work, since player has not relationship with sports*/
    @foreach ($ps->game as $psg)
      {{$psg->id}}
      {{$psg->player_name}}
      {{$psg->sports_name}}
      {{$psg->scores}}
    @endforeach    
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

is there other way to achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried has many trough relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading): Player hasMany games, games belongsTo a sport.

```
$player=Player::with('games','games.sport')->find($id);
foreach($player->games as $game)
{
   echo $game;
   echo $game->sport;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The relation between `Player` and `Sport` is also the [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

So you can define a `sports` relation in `Player` model as:

```
public function sports()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sport', 'games')->withPivot('scores');
}
```

Then in your view you can write your `foreach` as:

```
@foreach($player as $p)
  @foreach ($p->sports as $s)
      {{$p->player_name}}
      {{$s->sports_name}}
      {{$s->pivot->scores}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```